# Updating second table based on first table data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to update Final score table based on Evaluation table. Can you please tell me what is wrong with below code and how do you finally save the data in the second table?

**Evaluation.rb**

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer
  belongs_to :supervisor
  after_save :eval_score_calculator

  def eval_score_calculator
    finalscore.score_calculator
  end
end
```

**Final_score.rb**

```
class FinalScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer

  def score_calculator
    @job_performance_avg = (:job_knowledge_score.to_s.to_f + :quality_score.to_s.to_f + :quantity_score.to_s.to_f)/3
    @interpersonal_skills_avg = (:team_contribution_score.to_s.to_f + :seeks_to_improve_score.to_s.to_f + :accepts_responsibility_score.to_s.to_f + :interaction_with_others_score.to_s.to_f+ :integrity_and_trust_score.to_s.to_f)/5
    @organization_skills_avg = (:organization_planning_score.to_s.to_f + :use_of_company_resources_score.to_s.to_f + :time_management_score.to_s.to_f )/3
    @final_score  = 0.5 * @job_performance_avg + 0.25 * @interpersonal_skills_avg + 0.25 * @organization_skills_avg
  end
end
```

Comment: No relationship between Evaluation and FinalScore. what is that finalscore ??

Comment: Oh sorry..Evaluation has_one :finalscore

Comment: What's the name of the column from FinalScore you want to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you want to update a table you need to `.save` in order to store the changes in database.
So after you get all the calculations you should modify the columns you want and then save it. (assuming final_rating is a column of Finalscore table)

```
class FinalScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  #other belongs_to
  belongs_to :evaluation

  def score_calculator(param1, param2)
    #your calculations...

    #update the fields you want of this final score
    self.onething = param1
    self.anotherthing = param2

    #and at the end save it
    self.save
  end
end
```

2) Inside your evaluation class, you should first retrieve the final score object associated to this evaluation and then call the `score_calculator`. (Assuming you have the id of the finalscore object associated to this evaluation as a column in your evaluation table, and `Finalscore` as the name of the table)

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
   #belongs_to ...
   after_save :eval_score_calculator
   has_one :finalscore

  def eval_score_calculator

    #finds the finalscore object in the table of finalscores
    Finalscore.find(finalscore_id).score_calculator(a ,b)

  end

end
```

`a` and `b` are fields from your `evaluation` object you pass to `score_calculator` in order to calculate the score of the evalutaion and then save it into the `finalscore` table. You have this `finalscore` object updated and also associated to the `evaluation` with the field `finalscore_id` I suggested you below.

*If you don't have `finalscore_id` in your `evaluation` table I suggest you add it with a migration to simplify the usage and comply the relationships declared with `has_one` and `belongs_to` for this you could take a look at* http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

3) You are using `@` to every variable you declare, I just wonder why. `@myVar` is used to pass data among controllers and views. To define variables in your model you can just type it without `@`, anyways these won't be accesible in your views.

Comment: Ok..one more question. To do some calculations, The score_calculator method in FinalScore model either has to access whatever User entered in Evaluations/new screen or has to access the user entries posted  in Evaluation table or the eval_score_Calculator has to pass these arguments to score_calculator. Which should be the best option and how should it be implemented?

Comment: Ok. Let me see if I got your question. Inside the `FinalScore` model you can use any of the fields `FinalScore` has; the way you use it is with an instance of a `FinalScore` object, so that instance has values in its fields, then these fields can be used inside any `def` in your model. If you want to pass arguments to `def score_calculator` you simply add `def score_calculator(myParam, secondParam)` and use those params inside this `def`, and when you call it from `def eval_score_calculator` give it the params it needs, like so: `Finalscore.find(finalscore_id).score_calculator(param1, param2)`

Comment: Thanks..But I am facing a problem when I invoke score_calculator using after_save. When I say after_save :eval_score_calculator(param1, param2) it throws an error. Also I will have to compute and post data in Finalscore model using columns in Evaluation model not FinalScore.  Please let me know which approach is best.

Comment: That's because you misunderstood something, check my answer it's edited